# 3 ноября исполнился бы 131 год. Правильное ли это выражение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

3 ноября исполнился бы 131 год. Правильное ли это выражение? Или со дня рождения прошло 131 год

Answer (score 2):

**3 ноября исполнился бы 131 год. Правильное ли это выражение?**

Нет, так говорить не следует. Ответ на этот вопрос можно найти в журнале ["Наука и жизнь", №11, 1999 г.](https://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/9894/). Вот как звучал вопрос в №10:

> СТОЛЬКО-ТО ЛЕТ ТАКОМУ-ТО ИЛИ СО ДНЯ РОЖДЕНИЯ ТАКОГО-ТО?
>
> В прессе, на телевидении, на радио по-разному сообщают о юбилейных
>   датах. Вот несколько примеров.
>
> 1. 19 мая исполнилось бы 80 лет со дня рождения Наталии Иосифовны Ильиной. (“Литературная газета”.)
> 2. Эта передача расскажет о римской ветви семейства Толстых, посвящается она любимой дочери писателя Татьяне Львовне
>      Толстой-Сухотиной. В октябре этого года ей было бы 130 лет. (“Семь
>      дней”.)
> 3. 140 лет исполнилось в этом году Эмилю Верхарну. (Радио России.)
> 4. Недавно — 9 ноября по новому стилю — Ивану Сергеевичу Тургеневу исполнилось бы 180 лет. (“Русский язык”.)
>
> Хороши ли эти формулировки?

Ответ Н.Еськовой:

> Есть две конструкции для сообщения о юбилейной дате: "столько-то лет
>   такому-то" и "столько-то лет со дня рождения такого-то". Было бы
>   хорошо, если бы они были последовательно разграничены: первая - юбилей
>   отмечается при жизни, вторая - юбилей посмертный. На практике нередко
>   вторая конструкция фигурирует, когда юбиляр жив-здоров, и гораздо
>   естественнее было бы сообщить, сколько ему исполнилось лет. С другой
>   стороны, иногда сообщают, что исполнилось столько-то лет тому, кого
>   уже давно нет в живых (см. пункт 3).
>
> Но придумали еще одну конструкцию: "Сегодня такому-то исполнилось бы
>   (или было бы) столько-то лет" (см. пункты 2 и 4). С ней надо
>   обращаться осторожно: она вполне уместна, если покойный юбиляр мог бы
>   реально дожить до указанного возраста. Но чем больше лет прошло со дня
>   рождения того, кого уже нет с нами, тем больше опасность, что такая
>   фраза произведет комическое впечатление. Вот как эта конструкция была
>   пародирована:
>
> "Сегодня известному восточному мыслителю и поэту Абулькасиму Фирдоуси
>   исполнилось бы 1050 лет..."
>
> Это из "Кнышуток" (шуток Андрея Кнышева), напечатанных на 16-й
>   странице "Литературной газеты" (5 июня 1991).
>
> Но иногда, совсем запутавшись (а не ради шутки), создают "шедевры"
>   вроде пункта 1. Как вы понимаете, любое количество лет со дня рождения
>   исполняется без всякого "бы"!
>
> А отмечая недавно 100-летие Хемингуэя, использовали, кажется, все
>   возможные формулировки, в том числе: "Сегодня Хемингуэю исполнилось
>   100 лет" и "Сегодня Хемингуэю исполнилось бы 100 лет".

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, выражение с *исполнилось* можно употребить как в форме "3 ноября имяреку исполнился бы 131 год" (если бы он был жив), так и в форме "3 ноября исполнится 131 год со дня рождения имярека". Первое по смыслу немного смешно (никто не доживает до 131 года).